# can no longer load express app webpages

Tags: node.js, express

So i've been working on getting a user authentication system going and then I encountered a problem where my webpages would no longer load. `npm start` works fine and the server appears to be running. going to localhost just shows that the bar keeps loading and never eventually loads (before the webpages loaded instantly). I have no idea what I changed but tried to revert as much of the code to the original but still no dice. let me know if any other files are needed. thanks in advance

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var flash = require('connect-flash');

// var users = require('./routes/users');
var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser('ground glass'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(flash);
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));

app.use('/', routes);
//app.use('/users', users);


// passport config
// var Account = require('./models/accounts');
//passport.use(new LocalStrategy(Account.authenticate()));
//passport.serializeUser(Account.serializeUser());
//passport.deserializeUser(Account.deserializeUser());

// mongoose
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

 // Using the flash middleware provided by connect-flash to store messages in session
 // and displaying in templates
//var flash = require('connect-flash');
//app.use(flash());

//require('./routes/index')(app);

/*
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));*/

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err.status = 404;
    next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});


module.exports = app;
```

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'test' });
});


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: not sure if this helps anyone but I get this `GET / - - ms - -` that comes up on the console every now and then

Comment: When you hit the route, what is returned to your browser? What are the response header fields? What does the HTML look like?

Comment: And are you sure there's an app.use call that takes a path and a router? It looks to me from the doc that app.use(path,handler) takes a handler or an array of handlers rather than a router object.

Comment: nothing is returned to the browser... it just loads. when I try and console.log() something in the router.get... it doesn't even reach that function.

Comment: @Szpok I'm facing this same issue. Did you ever figure out a solution?